# Access configuration object while configuring services

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, console-application, .net-5, .net-6.0

In a console application, rather than building the IConfiguration and IServiceProvider manually, I'm trying to use the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` process:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<Whatever>();
    })
    .Build();
```

I can get the configuration object after building the host. But what I'm looking for is a way to get the config object while still in the `ConfigureServices` body, so that I can bind a config section to the service provider.

Something like:

```
AccountConfiguration accountConfig = new();
config.Bind("AccountConfiguration", accountConfig);
services.AddSingleton(accountConfig);
// or
services.Configure<AccountConfiguration>(config.GetSection("AccountConfiguration"));
```

Is there a way to access the config object while still configuring the services? Or a good way of adding an object to the service collection after the host has already been built?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of lambda passed to `ConfigureServices` is `HostBuilderContext` which exposes configuration property - [`IConfiguration Configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0):

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        IConfiguration config = context.Configuration;
        // use config
        services.AddSingleton<Whatever>();
    })
    .Build();
```